# Kubuntu 18.04, screen resolution changes after system hibernates

Tags: kubuntu, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I am having an intermittent issue with my monitor. It resizes after resuming from hibernate mode.

Here is my graphics hardware:

```
me@computer:~$ /usr/bin/inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
        Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: ati,amdgpu (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,radeon)
        Resolution: 1280x720@60.02hz
        OpenGL: renderer: Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.23.0, 4.15.0-45-generic, LLVM 7.0.1)
        version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.0-devel (git-932ed9c 2019-01-29 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
```

Before hiberbate (normal operation, 1360x768):

```
me@computer:~$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
1360x768      60.02*+
1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
1152x864      59.97  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      60.00    58.98  
800x600       60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After hibernate (squashed up 1280x720):

```
me@computer:~$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1280x720      60.02* 
1024x768      60.02  
800x600       60.02  
640x480       60.02  
HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The resolution corrects itself on reboot. I would prefer to stop the issue or correct the resolution without a reboot.

In syslog there are a bunch of messages in line with the time the system is resumed where it looks like kscreen.xrandr is trying to call for 1360x768, fails and then calls 1280x720.

I would appreciate any help people can offer. Perhaps just a bug with the drivers?
I am using this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: Should have added, the computer doesn't hibernate; just the monitor.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see which scripts are run when your system Hibernates/Resumes. Some of these are aimed at graphic cards.

Comment: @waltinator sorry, wasn't clear; the computer doesn't hibernate, just the monitor. I get `No manual entry for pm-action` for `man pm-action`